# AutoCloseable Lock

Tags: java, locking, lombok

Surprisingly, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6965731/581205) has no satisfactory answer. A safe usage of a `LockCloseable` would be like

```
try (LockCloseable lockCloseable = LockCloseable.lock(lock)) {
    doSomethingUnderLock();
} // automatic release
```

or using [@lombok.Cleanup](https://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html)

```
{
    @Cleanup LockCloseable lockCloseable = LockCloseable.lock(lock)
    doSomethingUnderLock();
} // automatic release when the scope is left
```

while all answers either create a new lock (non-sense) or when locking return an existing object (dangerous) or return void (unusable with try-with resources).

So I'm giving it a try:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class MgLockCloseable implements AutoCloseable {
    public static MgLockCloseable tryLock(Lock lock) {
        return new MgLockCloseable(lock.tryLock() ? lock : null);
    }

    public static MgLockCloseable lock(Lock lock) {
        lock.lock();
        return new MgLockCloseable(lock);
    }

    @Override public void close() {
        if (isLocked()) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return lock != null;
    }

    @Nullable private final Lock lock;
}
```

Notes:

- `RequiredArgsConstructor` comes from lombok and does exactly what the name says.
- I implemented only the two methods I need.
- It's only `AutoCloseable` as the closing is not idempotent.

Comment: Interesting related reading: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074083/core-java/project-coin--the-try-with-resources-lock-support-debate.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574353/any-risk-in-a-autocloseable-wrapper-for-java-util-concurrent-locks-lock.

Comment: @Tunaki Indeed. In my use case, I needn't care about allocation cost, but I guess, for some uses it could be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

`MgLockCloseable.tryLock()` is not practical if acquired in a loop. This is how one would do this traditionally:

```
while (!lock.tryLock()) {
    sleep();
}
try {
    // do locked stuff
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

This is what is necessary to do this with `MgLockClosable`:

```
boolean processed = false;
while (!processed) {
    try (AutoClosable closable = MgLockClosable.tryLock()) {
        if (closable.isLocked()) {
            processed = true;
            // do locked stuff
        } else {
            sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

---

From the javadoc of `AutoClosable.close()`:

> implementers of this interface are strongly encouraged to make their close methods idempotent.

It's easy to make the `close()` implementation idempotent and is useful in some scenarios:

```
try (MgLockClosable writeLocked = MgLockClosable.lock(getLock().writeLock()) {
    try (MgLockClosable ignored = MgLockClosable.lock(getLock().readLock()) {
        // do write lock related stuff
        writeLocked.close();
        // do write lock unrelated stuff (potentially slow)
    }
}
```

The code demonstrates read/write lock downgrading. Splitting the logic into two blocks, the one requiring a write lock, and the one requiring a read lock, has the benefit of improved concurrency. At the same time the code is still save, since both locks will be released in any case.

---

I'd swap the two lines in `lock()`. If the constructor throws (for any reason we don't know at the moment) the lock will never be unlocked. On the other hand, if you swap the lines: if the constructor throws, the lock will not be acquired. If `Lock.lock()` throws the instance of `MgLockCloseable` will never be returned.

Comment: Is there a need to call `tryLock()` in a loop when there's `tryLock(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit)`? Even when using a loop, you could simplify it with `break`.

Comment: True. But MgLockClosable does not expose tryLock(long, TimeUnit). break would simplify the code but not significantly.

Comment: True. It surely should expose `tryLock(long, TimeUnit)` and this can be trivially done, but I only implemented what I needed. +1 for idempotency and line swapping.